# CosmosDb Delete in Loop fails after one deletion

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a console app to delete documents from CosmosDB based on a partition that we have set up.

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(Config["CosmosEndpoint"]), Config["CosmosAuthkey"]))
            {
                var db = Options.Env.ToUpper().Equals("CI") ? Config["CiDatabase"] : Config["QaDatabase"];
                var tenantString = $"{Options.Tenant}-{Options.Language}";
                Log.Information($"Deleting {tenantString} from {db}-{Config["CosmosCollection"]}");

                var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(
                                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db, Config["CosmosCollection"]),
                                    "SELECT * FROM c",
                                    new FeedOptions()
                                    {
                                        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(tenantString)
                                    }
                                ).ToList();

                Log.Information($"Found {query.Count} records for Tenant: {tenantString}");

                if (query.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var doc in query)
                    {
                        Log.Information($"Deleting document {doc.Id}");

                        await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink,
                                new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(tenantString) });

                        Log.Information($"Deleted document {doc.Id}");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.Information($"Tenant: {tenantString}, No Search Records Found");
                }
            }
```

This never reaches the line `Log.Information($"Deleted document {doc.Id}");` but also does not seem to throw an exception. I have wrapped the call in a try/catch for DocumentClient/ArgumentNull Exception in an attempt to see what it was but it just bombs on the delete call. It does, however, always delete one document.

This tells me that my config must be correct as I am connecting and querying and even deleting but not for all documents in the query. Even more strange is that I have copied this from another application that I wrote earlier where this code works.

- Is there an upper limit on connecting meaning I need to delay my loop
  some?
- Why do I not see an exception when using a try/catch?

Or is there another reason that I only seem to be able to delete one document at a time with this code?

Comment: Removing the await keyword allows this to work better but it still does not delete all of the documents returned by the query.

Comment: This seems to work

var result = client.DeleteDocumentAsync(doc.SelfLink,
                                new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(tenantString) }).Result;

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Ok I think I know what is going on here. I think the using clause I have wrapped this in initiates the IDisposable after the first result. This is why removing the await works as it does not collect up the rest of the iteration. I could remove the using block but I have left it without the await. Not sure which way around is better as the gains from await may be outweighed.